# Where are stored my emails?

Tags: debian, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I am newbie. I created mail server thanks to the [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin)

Everything works, but I want to make backup of my emails. I made `mysql` backup, but email are not there.

I checked `/var/mail/vhosts` and `/var/spool/postfix` and still nothing.

I read that email storage depends on configuration. My configurations files are the same like in in tutorial above.

Where are my emails?

Comment: Try /var/spool/mail - also look at /vat/log/maillog and ~user/Maildir (and variants) for hints - your mail cou and /vsr/spool/virtualmailld be stored anywhere depending on your config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Dovecot [Mail Location Settings](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/mail_location/):

> There are three different places where the mail location is looked up
>   from:
>
> 1. `mail_location` setting in dovecot.conf is used if nothing else overrides it
> 2. mail User Databases (`userdb`) overrides `mail_location` setting.
> 3. `location` setting inside namespaces overrides everything. Usually this should be used only for public and shared namespaces.

If you have followed the [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin) you have:

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
```

Where the [variables](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/mail_location/#variables) are:

> - `%n` User part in `user@domain`, same as `%u` if there’s no domain.
> - `%d` Domain part in `user@domain`, empty if there’s no domain.

Therefore, the mail is stored in `domain/user` directories under `/var/mail/vhosts/`. It's strange you didn't know, as following the tutorial you should have created those folders manually:

> We are going to create a folder for each domain that we register in
>   the MySQL table:
>
> ```
> mkdir -p /var/mail/vhosts/example.com
> ```